# How to add checkbox only in a particular column in RadGridView in c#

Tags: c#, radgridview

I want to add the checkbox column as the second column of the RadGridView.

```
radGridView1.DataSource = Adapter.showColumnNames(masterTab1.HeaderGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
radGridView1.Columns.Add(new GridViewCheckBoxColumn());
```

This code is displaying the checkboxes before and after the the data column.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Insert method.

The first parameter is the zero-based index of the column, and the second is the column itself.

Example:

```
radGridView1.DataSource = Adapter.showColumnNames(masterTab1.HeaderGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
radGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, new GridViewCheckBoxColumn());
```

Comment: But its thorwing me exception that Index must be within the bounds of the List.

Comment: The following code works for me, so maybe the problem is the DataSource:

radGridView1.Columns.Add("first");
radGridView1.Columns.Add("third");
radGridView1.Columns.Insert(1, new GridViewCheckBoxColumn());